# Different display in console in R and RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Following the code of a tutorial I defined class and methods for my function of linear regression.

```
data(cats, package="MASS")
linmodeEst <- function(x,y){

  qx   <- qr(x) # QR-decomposition
  coef <- solve.qr(qx,y) # solve(t(x)%*%x)%*%t(x)%*%y

  df     <- nrow(x)-ncol(x)
  sigma2 <- sum((y-x%*%coef)^2)/df
  vcov   <- sigma2 * chol2inv(qx$qr)

  colnames(vcov) <- rownames(vcov) <- colnames(x)

  list(coefficients = coef, vcov=vcov, sigma = sqrt(sigma2), df=df)
}

linmod <- function(x,...) UseMethod("linmod")

linmod.default <- function(x,y,...){
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  y <- as.matrix(y)

  est <- linmodeEst(x,y)

  est$fitted.values <- as.vector(x%*%est$coefficients)
  est$residuals     <- y - est$fitted.values
  est$call          <- match.call()
  class(est) <- "linmod"
  est
}

print.linmod <- function(x,...){
  cat("Call:\n")
  print(x$call)
  cat("\nCoefficients:\n")
  print(x$coefficients)
}

summary.linmod <- function(object,...){
  se <- sqrt(diag(object$vcov))
  tval <- coef(object)/se
  TAB <- cbind(Estimate = coef(object),
               StdErr = se,
               t.value = tval,
               p.value = 2*pt(-abs(tval), df=object$df))
  res <- list(call=object$call, coefficients=TAB)
  class(res) <- "summary.linmod"
  res
}

print.summary.linmod <- function(x,...){
  cat("Call:\n")
  print(x$call)
  cat("\n")

  printCoefmat(x$coefficients, P.value=TRUE, has.Pvalue=TRUE)
}
x = cbind(Const=1, Bwt=cats$Bwt)
y = cats$Hw
mod1 <- linmod(x,y)
summary(mod1)
```

So, in the `summary.linmod <- function(object,...)` I defined the table names: `Estimate, StdErr, t.value, p.value`. In R I get all the names in the header, in RStudio just StdErr. why is this happening?

My system: Linux 64bit, R 3.1.1

[image]

Comment: You might consider posting all relevant code so that the example is reproducible.

Comment: @jbaums thanks for adding the image! Also, just added the code of the example.

Comment: I am getting the same output in both, and both are missing headers except 'Stderr'. I also get a warning `Warning message:
In `$.data.frame`(cats, Hw) : Name partially matched in data frame`

Comment: R 3.1.0 on Windows (both 64- and 32-bit) returns the same output as your RStudio screenshot, both from RStudio 0.98.953 and from the R terminal. (I also get @Ramnath's warning, though it can be disregarded.)

Comment: Replacing `TAB <- cbind` with `TAB <- data.frame` resolves this issue for me.

Comment: I don't get @Ramnath's warning, but yes let's ignore that. I guess I should have mentioned that I'm running R in Linux, but I guess this is obvious from the screenshot. Let's see if others get same/diff results.

Comment: @jbaums you're right! that works for me too!

Comment: For reference, the warning mentioned by @Ramnath refers to the fact that you've supplied an incomplete element name when creating `y = cats$Hw` (the full column name is `Hwt`). Where possible, partially matching column names are selected (more info at `?'$'`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation at `?cbind` states that: "For cbind (rbind) the column (row) names are taken from the colnames (rownames) of the arguments if these are matrix-like."

In constructing `TAB`, you are binding 3 single-column matrices (i.e. `coef(object)`, `tval`, and `2*pt(-abs(tval), df=object$df)`, to `se` (a non-matrix vector with 2 elements). Because of the behaviour quoted above, `cbind` uses the matrices' names (empty) to name the matrix-like columns of `TAB`.

Use `cbind.data.frame` or simply `data.frame` to construct `TAB`, and your summary output will have the expected names:

```
summary.linmod <- function(object,...){
  se <- sqrt(diag(object$vcov))
  tval <- coef(object)/se
  TAB <- data.frame(Estimate = coef(object),
                    StdErr = se,
                    t.value = tval,
                    p.value = 2*pt(-abs(tval), df=object$df))
  res <- list(call=object$call, coefficients=TAB)
  class(res) <- "summary.linmod"
  res
}


> summary(mod1)
# Call:
# linmod.default(x = x, y = y)
# 
#       Estimate   StdErr t.value p.value    
# Const -0.35666  0.69228 -0.5152  0.6072    
# Bwt    4.03406  0.25026 16.1194  <2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```